# php: Warning: rename The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. (code: 123)

Tags: php, rename

Since I am trying to copy my file I am getting this error, I am using windows 8.1

> Warning: rename(../user/will/video/javascript-toggle-buttons-MonMar09122015-7491.mp4,../user/will/video/video-SunMar-15-18:03-2015-shared.mp4): The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. (code: 123) in E:\xampp\htdocs\social_media\root\php_parsers\status_system.php on line 353

this is I am trying to do,

```
if (file_exists("../user/$author/$folder/$file")) {
    if (!file_exists("../user/$account_name/$folder")){
        mkdir("../user/$account_name/$folder/",0755);
    }
    copy("../user/$author/$folder/$file","../user/$account_name/$folder/$file");
    $dbnewFile = $newFileName.'.'.$fileExt;
    // for rename purpose
    $oldName = "../user/$account_name/$folder/$file";
    $newName = "../user/$account_name/$folder/$dbnewFile";
    rename($oldName, $newName);
}
```

What's wrong with this? I am tired of watching this error :( and really frustrated.

Comment: The warning comes with information that says the problem is line 353.  Label these lines for us so we know which one is 353.  The problem may be that you are using `!file_exists()` to check for a directory, and not a file.

Comment: the line 353 is `rename($oldName, $newName);` and my `!file_exists()` working fine that is for create directory if not exists to use.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is in the file name `video-SunMar-15-18:03-2015-shared.mp4`. Colons are not allowed in Windows filenames.

Please see [this list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#naming-conventions) for more information about invalid characters.

Comment: Thank you very much for help :) :D , big help for me, I really appreciate.
God bless you. :D