# Laravel file upload or move issue with special characters

Tags: php, laravel, file, upload

I've implemented successfully in my app some of the Laravel file management functionalities : upload, download, move. At least I would've said it is successful cause it works fine until I find out I'm getting **issues** when storing **files with some special characters in their filename/path**.

In my case I've remarked it with the colon character. There are other characters which can trigger that. I can successfully register a form with a file input: I mean without those characters, I can without any problem upload, download and edit. But once I get a colon for example in my filename, an input field which is used for the path: (`$filename = $request->input('inputFileName') .'.'. $file->getClientOriginalExtension();`  `$path = $file->storeAs('folder',$filename);`) I get problem.

First, the filename isn't anymore well recorded: from the colon, the remaining of the filename is not registered. For example, let's say the input for the filename is `a:b`; in my folder I'll get `a` registered instead and without the extension. No need to say this makes me get the `File not found at path` error.. when wanting to download. I get that error too when I want to change that filename with a colon to an other. Another thing I remark  with the editing too is the fact that I can't rename a file without those characters (colon here) to one with it. When doing so I get the `php: Warning: rename The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. (code: 123)`. I've looked for it and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29053800/php-warning-rename-the-filename-directory-name-or-volume-label-syntax-is-inc). It seems to be related to the OS file system. I'm on Windows 10 OS using Laravel 5.8.

Have anyone of you already faced this issue and how did you manage with this? Does Laravel got something to deal with this?.. Any help or suggestion will be very appreciated

Comment: what do you mean with a colon character ?

Comment: @TedAaron to make life easier, don't use the filename just generate a random name and assign it to database. How to generate? `$extension = File::extension($file->getClientOriginalName()); $filename = rand() . "." . $extension;`

Comment: @TeomanTıngır the colon `:`

Comment: @JGEscarilla thank you for the answer. The thing is the web app I'm building I need to have the file uploaded with a precise input filename so I'mma really need the file to have a clear name so the users know what it is about

Comment: @TedAaron I see, I understand. Bdw in addition of my answer, just for bases, make try on facebook or any sites, try to download any image from there, you will notice, it is unreadable, mostly random. I think why most of the sites preferred random filename to prevent duplicate names.

Comment: Yes I remarked that indeed and it's true things will be easier, simple and will work for everyone like that finally. Thank you for taking time to answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont save the files with their original name, just generate a random name to save the file and keep the original name (if needed) in your database or event in another file beside the saved file. Never trust client side inputs.

Comment: thank you for your answer, you're right.. I get what you're saying but for the needs of the app I'm bulding the filename must be clear when downloaded.. Isn't there for example a way to control or force the user to enter the right characters I mean those which do not trigger problem in the file system somehow..?

Comment: @TedAaron as i said, you can save the original filename somewhere else and the when the user downloads the file, set it's name to that. in laravel you can do it like this `return response()->download($pathToFile, $name);`